# Control labels on language change

Tags: c#-4.0

I have several button control labelled: Add, Edit, copy, delete, multiple vehicle selection. I have an option in menu bar to change the language (english, spanish, german etc...). Is there any easy way to change the button control labels based on selected language in windows form?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by switching the language for application and applying this change to all open forms and their controls:

```
private void barButtonItem1_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "de-DE")
            {
                CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                ChangeLanguage("en-US");
            }

            else
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
                ChangeLanguage("de-DE");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        { }
    }

    private static void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
    {
        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            localizeForm(frm, lang);
        }
    }

    private static void localizeForm(Form frm, string lang)
    {
        var manager = new ComponentResourceManager(frm.GetType());
        manager.ApplyResources(frm, "$this");
        applyResources(manager, frm.Controls, lang);
    }

    private static void applyResources(ComponentResourceManager manager, Control.ControlCollection ctls, string lang)
    {
        foreach (Control ctl in ctls)
        {
            // here your logic should be accurate enough to apply each control on form
            // This is just an example and may or may not work, just giving a thought that you can do it in this way
            manager.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
            applyResources(manager, ctl.Controls, lang);
        }
    }
```

I hope this will help you to indulge more into it. :)

Comment: Good to hear that it helped you ! You can mark this as answer to your question, so it will help others too. Happy coding :)